# What is the first movie with a one-bit color depth?

Tags: first-appearance, effects, cinematography

I have just seen a movie, *Renaissance* (2006), with a one-bit color depth. Also, I couldn't find another movie with one-bit color depth.

What is the first movie that has one-bit color depth throughout the entire movie?

Comment: I see greys; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ftZhphGgwo

Comment: Oops, you are right.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=swh448fLd1g - Fantasmagorie is literally the first (ever) cartoon feature film. It uses only white on black, and even then they've used scuffing of the film stock to create a grey miasma

Comment: This is not a valid argument against existence of a one-bit color depth movie.

Comment: In addition to Fantasmagorie's drawing on film, there are animated films using a silhouette style; [The Adventures of Prince Achmed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Prince_Achmed) from 1926 is well known but I'm sure the same technique was used before in shorter films.

Comment: @StuartF - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_9L7r8NIBc - This is also extremely far away from being a monochrome. I see a wide variety of colours and hues being used

Comment: Maybe re-edit the question, since Renaissance is not 1-bit. The original prints of "Prince of Achmed" featured color tinting, thus also not 1-bit. If you're talking about true 1-bit I'm guessing it will be a digitally-made (or at least edited) movie, since even hard shadows will have some gray in it.

Comment: I would think the first movie made "as asked" is probably going to be a tech demo for xerox or apple.